# GCC doesn't optimize inline assembly "=g" outputs to be memory operands when you use a temporary which is later assigned to a global?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I have setup an example on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Wb179bvoP):

```
int global;

static inline int return3()
{
    int ret;
    __asm__("mov %0, 3"
            : "=g" (ret));
    return ret;
}

void f(int x)
{
    global = return3();
}
```

The compiler (GCC 12.2) outputs this:

```
f:
        mov eax, 3
        mov     DWORD PTR global, eax
        ret
global:
        .zero   4
```

I don't understand why the assembled code uses `eax`. The `return3` function is inline and the asm statement has the `g` constraint (which means register, memory or constant), so why can't it generate this?:

```
f:
        mov     DWORD PTR global, 3
        ret
global:
        .zero   4
```

Interestingly, in this [test](https://godbolt.org/z/5v9veo447), with the `m` constraint, the generated code first allocates space on the stack and saves the `3` there, then moves it to `eax` and only then moves it to `global`:

```
f:
        sub     esp, 16
        mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 3
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
        mov     DWORD PTR global, eax
        add     esp, 16
        ret
global:
        .zero   4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC<sup>1</sup> inline asm `"m"` or `"g"` operands only ever use the address of the actual C object you used, not some other object it's later assigned to.  In your case that's the local variable `ret`.

---

If the inline asm took the address of its output operand (using `lea`), it should only get the address of `global` if you used `"=g"(global)`.  Which does in fact happen: https://godbolt.org/z/YYjzs5P3n

If the asm stored multiple different temporary values in that operand, a signal handler shouldn't be able to see them in `global`.  (I know it's not `volatile` so that's a bit questionable, but do note that at least GNU C de-facto supports rolling your own atomics using `asm` so a cautious approach makes sense.)

If the `asm` also accessed `global` by name, it would be a problem if the value of `global` had already changed from using `%0` as scratch space.  That wouldn't actually be safe here because there's no `"memory"` clobber to tell the compiler this `asm` statement might read or write a C variable that isn't an explicit operand.

Perhaps you could call it a missed-optimization that GCC doesn't pick memory when there's no `"memory"` clobber, but there are cases where it needs to not do that.  The compiler internals are probably complicated enough.   (It's only a missed optimization if you discount the other factors, like taking the address, or possibly inventing extra writes to the non-atomic / non-volatile `global`.)

---

**Footnote 1** Clang `"g"` or `"=g"` does sometimes invent a temporary and then copy, which is weird.

https://godbolt.org/z/ochK7GzWf isn't quite that, just showing that it always picks memory for `g`, and with Intel syntax in fact shows it inventing `mov [esp], 3`, ambiguous operand-size because it doesn't print memory operands with `dword ptr` the way GCC does.  Intel-syntax inline asm support is new for clang.

TODO: cook up an example of clang's `"g"` inventing a temporary for input or output, e.g. when it had the value of a global in a register, it might spills it to the stack instead of to its permanent address IIRC.

Often it's a good idea to write `"r,m"` multi-alternative constraints for clang if you want to try to give it (or GCC) the option of picking memory.  Clang will pick `r` for an input at least.  But in this case `"=r,m"` didn't help.